# Entity Framework Tracking Question

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity

I'm using the code-first approach and have made a decision to not support lazing loading for my entities. So to help clarify my understanding, in order for EF to utilize lazy loading, ALL properties (scalar and navigation) must be designated as virtual? Does the same hold true for change tracking (ALL properties) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading needs all navigation properties virtual and dynamic change tracking needs all mapped non navigation properties virtual. These two sets are disjunctive.

Comment: ok, to confirm, if i want to have my entities support lazy loading and change tracking, i basically need all scalar (mapped) properties marked as virtual?

Comment: If you want to have both dynamic change tracking and lazy loding you need all mapped (scalar and complex) and navigation properties virtual.

Comment: can you please look at the following question i also have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687795/entity-framework-configuration-question-ef-code-first